# SSH using paramiko: Able to ssh into one MacBook, but not into the other. Both connected to so same Wifi and internet working

Tags: macos, ssh, paramiko

**Background:**
I have two MacBook Pro. Lets call them: Machine A and Machine B. Both are connected to the same WiFi network. Both have internet connection working on them.

Using the following python code (run from a third 'host' machine), I am successfully able to establish SSH connection with Machine A.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('172.xxx.xx.xxx', port=22, username='aaaaa', password='bbbbb')
```

**Issue:**
When I try to establish connection with Machine B, I see the following error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.xxx.xx.xxx
```

**Question:**
Since individual machines have internet working on them, I am intrigued why one is able to establish SSH connection while other is not. I verified that the IP, username and password for Machine B is correct.

1. Please chime in with debugging suggestions
2. I have always used `port 22` as the default in my code. Is there someway to determine the port# for Machine B?

PS- I am new to using MacBooks and paramiko. Maybe I am missing something basic here.

Comment: Can you connect with `ssh` from Machine B? If you can post its verbose output (`-vvv`)

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved by enabling Remote login for all users in Machine B.